# Can the Fourier Transform be used to solve any Differential Equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Does it have any limitations, or can it be used to solve any and all of them?

i.e. Can it solve a PDE with inhomogeneous or homogeneous boundary conditions, periodic boundary conditions, dirichlet boundary conditions, etc? Can it solve PDEs regardless of order or type (diffusion, Poisson 2-3D, Wave 1-3D, etc.)?

I ask because I am having some issues trying to use it to solve a PDE and am starting to grow suspicious of whether or not it is even applicable to my problem and whether or not I should switch methods.

Comment: "I ask because I am having some issues trying to use it to solve a PDE" And what is this PDE?

Comment: There's no general solution method that works for all differential equations.

Comment: @Winther I would use LaTex in comments if I knew how so I apologize if this looks a bit messy. The PDE I am working on is the 2D Poisson's Equation of the form Laplacian(u(x,y)) = f(x,y) where I have chosen f(x,y) = 2^(4*a) * (1-x)^a * x^a * (1-y)^a * y^a where I have chosen a = 1. This creates a opening up paraboloid on the boundary [0,1] x [0,1] and I have assumed Dirichlet Boundary Conditions on all 4 boundaries. It has a minimum at z = -16. The solution, u(x,y), should be a flipped image being a opening down paraboloid, but with a maximum at z = 1.

Comment: @Karl I thought Green's function was supposed to be able to solve all PDEs.

Comment: @ResearcherR: Not all PDEs are **linear**!

Comment: @ResearcherR: And by the way, math markup in comments works just like in questions and answers (just put it inside dollar signs).

Comment: @HansLundmark Are you saying that Fourier Transforms are limited in their ability to solve PDEs such that they are only capable of solving ones that are **linear**? I am attempting to solve the Poisson's Equation which **is** linear and I'm still having a rough time of it. I am using a finite domain and am solving it by coding and trying to get both the expected solution and obtained solution to match. The shapes of the produced surfaces are similar, but the maximum z-value for the obtained solution is too small by a `factor of 10000`. Do you have any further insight into this?

Comment: The equation is of the form $\frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u(x,y)}{\partial y^2} = f(x,y)$ where I have chosen $f(x,y) = 2^{4a} * (1-x)^a * (1-y)^a * x^a * y^a$ and a is set to `a=1` for simplicity.

Comment: @HansLundmark Update: I fixed my code and the max value of the obtained solution is about `0.78` when it should be about `1.00`.

Comment: With Fourier transforms, Fourier series or Green's functions you are trying to construct solutions by **superposition** of simpler solutions, so of course you need linearity for that to work.

Comment: There is something called the inverse scattering transform (IST) which works for some very particular (“completely integrable”) nonlinear equations, such as the KdV equation. But even linear equation may be tricky to handle by transform methods, for example $u_t + u_x + u_{xxx} = 0$ for positive $x$ and $t$ with $u(0,t)=0$ and $u(x,0)$ given; this particular example comes from Fokas's book *A Unified Approach to Boundary Value Problems*, which explains what the difficulty is and what to do about it.

Comment: @HansLundmark I see! So, `transform methods` actually can contain within them some sort of trick necessary to arrive to the desired result for certain `PDEs`. I'm still new to solving PDEs of `second order` and in general, and this is a technique that I picked up for a `research project`, and I am learning as I go along. The `Fourier Transform method` was suggested to me by my professor since I'm dealing with massive arrays of data and it's one of the most efficient methods. But, before I worked with any data, I first needed to get it to work on a relatively simple sample and go from there.

Comment: @HansLundmark I'll have to look into that source if I can spare the cash; I've bought about 4 books on the subject of PDEs and Fourier Transforms at this point. Might be worth it to get one more if you think it might be useful.

Comment: Fokas's book may or may not be useful, depending on your background. If you're new to the subject, it might be too difficult. And you'd definitely need to very comfortable with complex analysis.